# Google Identity One-Tap Sign-In Exception: Caller has been temporarily blacklisted due to too many canceled sign-in prompts

Tags: android, google-signin, google-identity

I am currently working on migration to One-Tap Sign-In, and after I tried few times on the device, my device gets blacklisted with exception (Caller has been temporarily blacklisted due to too many canceled sign-in prompts). Just wondering what's the threshold from being blacklisted? And is there anyway we can remove ourself from blacklist?

Also is this a correct behavior at all? after user try to open login and cancel few times and we have to fallback to the default google sign-in instead because the one-tap gets blacklisted?

Comment: I don't want to delete my data and the dialer trick isn't working... guess I'll just take a break

Comment: Update: I made some pasta and then cleared data on GPS and I still receive the error

Comment: Both tricks don't work on my Samsung Galaxy S22 base (maybe it's a device-specific thing?)

Comment: @Tigerrrrr as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77761949/18716297) suggests, on samsung phones you can't use samsung dialer app, instead just install and use [google's one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> If you encounter this 24-hour cooldown period during development, you can reset the cooldown by clearing Google Play services' app storage.

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap

Comment: Wow, didn't see this in the document. Thanks !

Comment: I don't get this. How to clear Google Play services' app storage?

Comment: Go to All Apps > Google Play Services > Clear Storage

Comment: In my case it was necessary to regenerate the client secret because I got an error like "10 Not whitelisted to use the API".

Answer (score 13):

> If you encounter this 24-hour cooldown period during development, you can reset the cooldown by clearing Google Play services' app storage. Alternatively, to toggle on/off this cool down on a test device and/or emulator alike, simply go to the Dialer app and input the following code: `*#*#66382723#*#*`. Upon submission, there will be no feedback, but your dialer will clear all input and may close. The cooldown should be toggled off after this. To toggle it back on, input the same code again.

just go to the Dialer app and input the following code: `*#*#66382723#*#*`
and try to call.

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap

Comment: This saves the day. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Dial this code in your dialer**

```
*#*#66382723#*#*
```

[Refer to this link from Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To toggle on/off cooldown on a test device and/or emulator alike, simply go to the Dialer app and input the following code: *#*#66382723#*#*.

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap

Answer (score 2):

For those who are trying to do it on Samsung phones, I managed to do it installing the "Phone by Google":
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer

After installing and setting it as default dialer it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from @mco post.
Just making the steps more clear here,

From Android device > "Settings" > "All Apps" or "Apps"> "Google Play Services" > "Storage" > "Clear cache"

Comment: Doesnt work, just tried it.

Comment: No't working, still throws an error "Caller has been temporarily blocked due to too many canceled sign-in prompts."