# accessing the googleOneTap function failure[10:Caller not whitelisted to call this API]

Tags: android, google-signin, google-one-tap

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/create-new-accounts
According to the above official documentation, when accessing the googleOneTap function, the third part Display the One Tap sign-up UI will occasionally receive To Error message of failure message 10: Caller not whitelisted to call this API, the google account of the phone itself is unavailable, how to deal with it.

Try to clear the local Google service data, restart the phone, but still can't restore the normal call.
Because this interface needs to be called repeatedly during debugging, I want to inform developers how to avoid or solve the [Caller not whitelisted to call this API] error

Comment: For one time reset see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63232906/2470346 or permanent disable : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72202792/2470346

Answer (score 1):

Wait about 15 minutes, until you're whitelisted and try again. It's not about code.